# How was Ultron aware of the Infinity Stone inside Loki's Scepter?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Avengers: Age of Ultron, we are aware that the Vision's body (the Vibranium-infused body Ultron had created) had the Mind Stone embedded in it and wielded the stone.  We also know that Ultron had broken apart the gem in Loki's scepter to get the Mind Stone (the yellow Infinity Stone).

My question is thus:  How did Ultron know the Scepter had an Infinity Stone in it?  It wasn't clear to me how he learned of the Stone inside the Scepter so how did he learn it existed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultron was born from Tony and Bruce analyzing and using code found *inside* the Scepter - from within the Mind Gem itself.

Tony and Bruce describe what they find inside the Scepter as something "like a computer", and know that "the jewel appears to be a protective housing for something inside."

Ultron knows about the existence of the Mind Gem because his own intelligence is based in part on the gem. But even if he didn't know because of that fact, he would have known that there was more to the jewel, from having access to all of Tony and Bruce's notes.